# how to get shopee api Authorization use php5.3

Tags: php, api, php-5.3

i want to get **shopee authorization** using the source code.
The language I use is php.5.3.2.
No matter how many times I search, I only have a demo about the higher version, so I can't find the answer I want to ask.

In shopee, you can calculate the default signature sequence and partner key value as "HMAC-SHA256" and create an autorization value. How can I write it in code?

i already get partner key.. but i don't know how to get authorization.

Comment: Considering that PHP 5.3 has been unsupported for 5 years (no security updates etc), I would _really_ recommend upgrading to a supported version. When you say _"I only have a demo about the higher version"_, what exactly do you mean? If you give some examples, we might be able to help you do the same in 5.3.

Comment: thank u for answer!! I want to upgrade too, but unfortunately I am not in a situation to upgrade. In other words, there is a demo code for the higher version on the Internet, but I can't find a demo code for my version.

Comment: The client library code I see says min code PHP7.1, which mens there is code in there stuff that requires PHP7.1. Looks like you have 2 choices. 1. Upgrade PHP 2. Dont use shopee.

Comment: Oh or 3. Rewite all the library you downloaded to work with PHP5.3

Comment: _"I am not in a situation to upgrade"_ - That's the part you should be working on instead. As mentioned, PHP 5.3 haven't even gotten any security updates in _5 years_. That's _very_ bad.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get shopee authorization, you need to prepare a header as mentioned below and send this header in curl headers with other required data. You can refer to the example given below.

```
    $secretKey = 'Your Secret Key' ;
    $baseUrl = "https://partner.shopeemobile.com/api/v1/";
    $action = 'The action you want to perform';
    $apiUrl = $baseUrl.$action ;
    $parameters = 'Required Parameters' ;
    $authorisation = $apiUrl."|".json_encode($parmaeters);
    $authorisation = rawurlencode(hash_hmac('sha256', $authorisation, $secretKey, 
    enter code herefalse));

    $header = array(
      'Content-Type: application/json',
      'Authorization: '.$authorisation,
    );
```

After preparing this, send $header in curl headers

YOUR CURL REQUEST WOULD BE LIKE THIS:

```
    $connection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($parameters));
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($connection);
    curl_close($connection);
```

Hope you get your query resolved by this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use npm package in your php app, you can use this code:

```
import { createHmac } from 'crypto';
    
const timestamp = getUTCUnixTimestamps();
const baseString = `${AppID}${Apipath}${timestamp}`;
const signCode = createHmac('sha256',shopeeAppSecret).update(baseString).digest('hex');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

To get the Shopee Auth code you'll need partnerID, partnerKey both can be seen on your Shopee Open Platform Console.
Next, is the API path for Authorization which is
https://partner.shopeemobile.com/api/v1/shop/auth_partner for V1
https://partner.shopeemobile.com/api/v2/shop/auth_partner for V2
both have different Auth processes

for V2

create a baseString consisting of
PartnerId,
API path (/api/v2/shop/auth_partner)
and Unix timestamp.
Create a signature using by hashing the baseString with your partnerKey.

```
$timest = time();
$tokenBaseString = $partnerID.$path.$timest;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $tokenBaseString, $partnerKey, false);
```

prepare the Auth URL like this

```
$host = 'https://partner.shopeemobile.com'
$path = '/api/v2/shop/auth_partner'
$partner_id = 123456
$timestamp = 'unix_timestamp' //authorization url expires in 5 minutes(because of timestamp expiration)
$sign = 'the_generated_signature'
$returnURL = 'https://yourReturnURL.com'
```

Auth URL will look like this

```
$AuthURL= $host.$path.'?partner_id='.$partner_id.'?timestamp='.$timestamp.'&sign='.$sign.'&redirect'.$returnURL;
```

Sample Auth URL

> https://partner.shopeemobile.com/api/v2/shop/auth_partner?partner_id=123456&timestamp=1648628444&sign=xxxxxxx&redirect=https://yourReturnURL.com

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I already updated my answer