# How to generate signature in Shopee 2.0 API request authentication?

Tags: php, api

I'm trying to get shop details thru https://partner.uat.shopeemobile.com/api/v2/shop/get

I tried this in php

```
$timestamp = time();
$partner_key = 123456;
$path = '/api/v2/shop/get';
$access_token = 'token...';
$shop_id = 22222;
$base_string = $partner_key . $path . $timestamp . $access_token . $shop_id;
$secret_key = 'secret...';

$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $secret_key);
```

but the response returned is wrong_sign.

I'm not sure if the path is correct. But that is what I understood in their documentation. https://open.shopee.com/documents?module=63&type=2&id=56

Comment: Hey Ian, did you try this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57788509/3080207 If so, what went wrong?

Comment: Hi Mikey, yes, i tried that for v1, but I think it doesn't work on apps created after deployment of v2 . Its response was partner and shop has no linked although i already linked them thru authorization url and in my sellers account. v2 has different calculation of signature than v1.

Comment: hello any correct answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
$partner_id = "xxxxxx";
$shop_id = "xxxxxx";
$secret_key = "yyyyyyyy";
$path = "/api/v2/auth/token/get"; //without the host
$base_str = $partner_id . $path . $timestamp . $shop_id;            
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $base_str,  $secret_key, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shopee signatures depends on the API you are calling

for Shop: Signature generated by partner_id, api path, timestamp, access_token, shop_id and partner_key via HMAC-SHA256 hashing algorithm.

setup the base string by concatinating the partner_id, api_path, timestamp(UNIX format), access_token and shop_id, then hash the base string via HMAC-SHA256 with the partner_key.

Setting up variable for signature creation:

```
$partner_id = 123456; //app_id of Shopee App
$api_path = '/api/v2/shop/get_shop_info'; //shopee API path
$timestamp = time(); //UNIX format of time, 5mins expiration time
$access_token = '...token'; //access_token from /api/v2/shop/auth_partner
shop_id = '654321' //unique shopee shop id
```

Creating the signature

```
$tokenBaseString = $partner_id.$api_path.$timestamp.$access_token.$shop_id;
$sign = hash_hmac('sha256', $tokenBaseString, $partner_key, false);
```

You can now use this signature to create a GET request from Shopee Open Platform

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://partner.shopeemobile.com/api/v2/shop/get_shop_info?access_token=$access_token&partner_id=$partner_id&shop_id=$shop_id&sign=$sign&timestamp=$timestamp',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Take note that you cannot reuse a signature for other API calls other than what is in the $api_path variable, within the timespan of 5mins from the set $timestamp, you'll need to create another signature after the timespan expires.

Note 2* Always check the API Documentation for generating signature, there are different types of parameters for generating a signature.

Note 3* Open API v1.0 will be deprecate by the end of 2022.